# Same To-Many-Relationship for different entities

Tags: database-design, doctrine-orm

This is probably a question a lot of people come across but I have not found a really satisfying answer so far, perhaps there isn't a perfect solution.

I have a lot of entities like let's say: Red, Green, Blue, Yellow etc...
All of these entities have nothing in common, but let's assume I want to have a couple of the entity "User" being responsible for these entities and I want to implement this relationship in my data model.

So the most natural solution is to create a couple of To-Many-Relationships like:
RedToUser (with foreign keys user_id and red_id), YellowToUser (with foreign keys user_id and yellow_id) and so forth.

While this is a very clear solution it isn't really convincing as I have many 'colors' and the relationship to User looks always the same apart from my foreign key 'color_id'. It feels like repeating myself over and over again.

Is there a best practise solution to design something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In data model terms, all these Red, Green, ... entities have a superentity, say `AttendedObject` with an m:n relationship to the user entity.

For mapping such superentity constructs to relational tables, there are different methods that are described in detail e.g. in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html. For a simple case like yours, I would define just one table with a discriminator that tells which type of entity is attended by a user, something like

```
Attendance(id, user_id, object_id, discriminator, ...)
```

where the discriminator takes the values of red, green, etc.